# dotnet restore unable to resolve Telerik.UI.for.AspNet on macOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, telerik, nuget

I'm trying to get a dotnet project working on macOS but I'm getting stuck when I run `dotnet restore`. All packages install fine except for my Telerik package:

`Unable to resolve 'Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core (>= 2016.3.1118)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.`

It's not a very descriptive error message so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Some things I've tried:

- Running `nuget restore` (results in error saying `The project file... .xproj was not found.` - even though it's there)
- Adding the package to `NuGet.Config`:

`<add key="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core.2016.3.1118" value="/Users/me/.nuget/packages/Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core/2016.3.1118" />`

[What the package looks like in my nuget packages directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0I8.png)

Comment: That's an odd package name. Are you sure you don't mean [`Kendo.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kendo.Mvc/2016.2.630-Preview)? Perhaps the 2016.3.1118 package was deleted from nuget due to its pretty unusual name format...

Comment: yeah it seemed like an unusual package to me. I wasn't able to install it from nuget, had to download and install locally. This is my first time working with dotnet core and resources are pretty hard to find. could I simply rename the directory? and then would I need to update refs in NuGet.Config and project.json?

Comment: I would delete the directory entirely, along with the entry in `NuGet.Config`, and just add the `Kendo.Mvc` package as any other package (in project.json, assuming you're using that version of the tooling).

Comment: same thing happens with Kendo.Mvc `Unable to resolve 'Kendo.Mvc (>= 2016.3.1118)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.` (in my project.json: `"Kendo.Mvc": "2016.3.1118",`)

Comment: Well yes, that's not the version number - see the nuget page, the latest stable version is 2016.2.616. There's also https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUICore/ which may be relevant to you (and does have a 2016.3.1118 version).

Comment: ah of course. thanks so much, this worked for me

Comment: Which one? I'll add an appropriate answer...

Comment: for sure. they both worked for me, but I think you're right - the one I was looking for was KendoUICore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's not the name of a Nuget package any more, as far as I can tell. I believe you want the [`KendoUICore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUICore/).

Based on the versions of that - which include 2016.3.1118 - I suspect that temporarily had the name "Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" before someone noticed that was a bizarre NuGet package name.

There's also [`Kendo.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kendo.Mvc) which has the description "Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0.0", but that doesn't have a version matching your expected version number.